# how to set different font-weights for characters in the same input box

Tags: javascript, css, input, autocomplete

I need to create an input box with an automplete functionality. So when a user enters "ja" , these first two characters will be in bold and "vascript" will be in grey.
For some reasons, I can't use the jquery autocomplete function. As the words that the user can enter are not that many, I created an array and  assigned for each abbreviation , the word that matches .

```
words= [{abbv:"J", word="JAVA"}, {abbv:"JA", word:"JAVASCRIPT"}]
```

Then, when the user starts entering the word, I look in the array for the word that matches with the "abbreviation", and display that word inside the box .
This works fine, the problem now is that I'm trying to highlight the first characters entered by the user and keep the rest of the word in grey.
What I'm trying to do looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/wyVJW/894/ , except that I would like the word to be displayed inside the input box itself and not in a scroll down menu.
How can I set a font weight only on the the characters entered and not on the whole input box?

Comment: use javascript ! :) as this is not possible through css only

Comment: Yes I'm using javascript

Comment: overlay a text container below the input which shows the suggestions :?

Comment: Actually I would like to suggestion to be displayed inside the input box (like when you make a research on google)

Comment: easy, and you don't need JS, just HTML:  use the list attribute on the input, and point it to a datalist tag that contains your suggestions.

Comment: if you closely monitor how google does it, there is disabled input just behind the main input which shows suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Input boxes do not support multiple styling. You need to overlay a DIV and use HTML within that DIV to "simulate" what you want to achieve visually and use CSS to make it still look as if it were an input box.

You will need to write some JavaScript to make this work.